# NestJS: Problem when setting up MailerModule with Gmail smtp

Tags: javascript, nestjs, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I am having a problem when setting up my MailerModule with Gmail Smtp in my NestJS Project.

I've already enable 2FA and create Google App Password in my google Accounts.

[image]

Here is my setup in `app.module.ts`:

```js
 MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          transport: {
            service: 'gmail',
            secure: false,
            auth: {
              user: configService.get('email.user'),
              pass: configService.get('email.pass'), // I Used Google App Password
            },
          },
        };
      },
    }),
```

When i run send mail code with this setup, the return always like this:

```
 ~ file: email.service.ts:94 ~ EmailService ~ sendEmail ~ err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.217.194.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.217.194.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Do anyone have a solution? Thanks

I've already tried to change my transport config to google XOAuth2, but it doesn't work.

```js
 MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          transport: {
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            port: 587,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
             type: "OAuth2",
             user: configService.get('email.user'),
             clientId: configService.get('email.clientId'), // Google API ClientID
             clientSecret: configService.get('email.clientSecret'), // Google API ClientSecret
             refreshToken: configService.get('email.refreshToken'), // Google API Refresh Token
            },
          },
        };
      },
    }),
```

Comment: can you change the port to 465 and keep secure true 

and in auth only use these two param -> user, pass

Comment: MailerModule.forRootAsync({
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
      return {
        transport: {
          host: "smtp.gmail.com",
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          service: 'gmail',
          auth: {
           user: configService.get('email.user'),
           pass: configService.get('email.pass'),
        },
        },
      };
    },
  }),

Comment: @dhruvinvaghasiya already done it, but the result remains the same. I'm consider moving to another smtp like (mailchimp)